# Как при помощи Simple Html Dom спарсить контент от тега html до тега body?

Tags: php, парсер

Не знаю как спарсить  контент одного сайта от тега html до body включительно.

Comment: А на других получается? покажите, как

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему в теге html от начала до тега body должен быть тег head, то есть просто взять его и всё:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://stackoverflow.com/');
$head = $html->find('head', 0);
echo $head->content;
```